# Is there a way to reference instances of a parent class in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, prototype

Can Cat obtain data from fluffy and garfield?

```
class Cat {
  constructor(name, weight) {
    this.name = name;
    this.weight = weight;
  }
}

fluffy = new Cat('fluffy', 15);
garfield = new Cat('garfield', 25);
```

Say I wanted to define a method that lists the names of all Cats.

```
Cat.listNames()
//['fluffy', 'garfield']
```

I searched through `Cat.prototype`, and couldn't find any useful methods or references to the child or even the child's `.__proto__`.

Comment: what `instances` do you mean here?

Comment: @appleapple fluffy and garfield

Comment: Do you want to iterate all instance? Nothing buildin afaict.

Comment: @appleapple yes, I figured, hoped I was missing something

Answer (score 0):

maybe this works

```
class Cat {
  Static CatList = [];
  constructor(name, weight) {
    this.name = name;
    this.weight = weight;
    Cat.CatList.push(this);
  }

  static listNames() {
    console.log(Cat.CatList);
  }
}
```

Comment: you may need something to unregister them. (which is tricky in javascript)

Comment: @appleapple can you link something on that? I'm testing this now and it might work.

Comment: @clinzy25 I mean if something goes out of reach from the program (like goes out of scope), it probably should be excluded from `CatList`. And the tricky part is there is no determined destructor in javasript. (there is no destructor at all afaict)

Comment: @KaMui it should be `static CatList` (lower case)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution to get Cats names:

```js
class Cat {
  constructor(name, weight) {
    this.name = name;
    this.weight = weight;
    Cat.CatNames.push(this.name);
  }
}

Cat.CatNames = [];
Cat.listNames = function() { 
  return Cat.CatNames;
}

var fluffy = new Cat('fluffy', 15);
var garfield = new Cat('garfield', 25);

console.log(Cat.listNames()); // ["fluffy", "garfield"]
```

Comment: this is the same as @KaMui 's answer 20min ago

Comment: well his code doesn't syntax correct so ok answer anyway.

Comment: Does it look to you like @KaMui answer's? It isn't!

Comment: oh, they're the same, just @KaMui 's answer wrongly type `static` as `Static`

Comment: OK, try to run both code (after fixing the `static` keyword in his answer) in Safari and you will find out the difference if you really think both answers are the same.

Comment: you can run it on IE and it would not work, doesn't mean they're different https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static#browser_compatibility

Comment: *they're not different*: they're the same by the standard, and you can use compiler like babel to migrate the lack of support.